# Regex-ing text in a textfield to be safe for URLs being loaded

Tags: ajax, regex, jquery, tumblr

You can demo this searching for the tag

> Black & White

at http://syndex.me

The logo of the site is a search field. If I search for "USA" it ajax loads all posts tagged "USA". However it does not work for "Black & White".
How can one check the value of the input field for potential non alphabetic characters and things like spaces, and then change it too a safe term, i.e.

> Black_%26_White

?

I know a little code but this kinda stuff is beyond me. I'm sure this question would be useful for other noobs. Thanks!

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    $('#syndex').keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        var syndex = $('input:text').val();
        $('body').load("http://syndex.me/tagged/"+ syndex,function(){
        $('input:text').val(syndex);
    });
       }        
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id="logo">
            <input id="syndex" type="text"/>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: not sure the site is sfw O_O ... maybe? but close enough for me to wonder...

Comment: on the edge with the supreme book cover by Richardson, but thats the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to strip everything except letters and numbers?

```
var syndex = $('input:text').val().replace(/\W\D/g, '');
```

Or do you want to convert special characters to a URI-friendly format?

```
$('body').load("http://syndex.me/tagged/"+ encodeURIComponent(syndex),function(){
```

Comment: Thanks David, nice function that. The second was the correct method. Cheers.